# c++ / c# Problem in named pipe

Tags: c#, c++

This is my c++ code

```
HANDLE hPipe = ::CreateNamedPipe(_T("\\\\.\\pipe\\FirstPipe"),
                                 PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                                 PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE,
                                 PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
                                 4096,
                                 4096,
                                 0,
                                 NULL);

ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL);

DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hPipe, lpBuffers, sizeof(LPWSABUF), &bytesWritten, NULL);//LPWSABUF is structure and lpBuffers is a variable of this structure
```

This is my C# code

```
uint dataLen = (uint)(br.ReadInt32());
string len = (dataLen).ToString();
listBox1.Items.Add(len);                        
IntPtr dataAdd = IntPtr.Zero;
string data = "";
if (IntPtr.Size == 4) dataAdd = (IntPtr)br.ReadInt32(); //ERROR
else dataAdd = (IntPtr)br.ReadInt64();
byte[] b = new byte[(int)dataLen];
Marshal.Copy(b, 0, dataAdd, (int)dataLen);
data = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(b);
listBox2.Items.Add(data);
```

In sixth line of C# code giving error. 
That End of the stream. I dont have any idea why it is giving error.

Here is the structure

```
typedef struct _WSABUF {
    ULONG len;     /* the length of the buffer */
    __field_bcount(len) CHAR FAR *buf; /* the pointer to the buffer */
}  WSABUF, FAR * LPWSABUF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LPWSABUF is pointer, its size is 32 or 64 bit. Possibly you mean this:

```
WriteFile(hPipe, lpBuffers, sizeof(WSABUF), &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

Comment: Yup.  Writing the *buf* pointer value is bound to cause trouble as well, using it will bomb when the C++ code is running in another process.  Write the string instead.

Comment: It gives error because you wrote only first 4 (or 8 in 64 bit computer) bytes to the pipe, instead of the whole structure.

Answer (score 0):

simply you have reached end of stream so end of stream exception is thrown.
If it's the first read command from file then your file is empty